# Xtend: Is there a counterpart to the Scala singleton object in Xtend

Tags: scala, singleton, xtend

I'm absolutely new to Xtend, but browsing the documentation and searching the Web unfortunately didn't bring up a clear answer.

I really do like the way one can define a *singleton object* in Scala.

Is there a counterpart to this in Xtend or do I have to fall back to implementing  the singleton pattern myself?

Comment: If you're comfortable with a bit of Java, just write a single-constant enum there.

Comment: No, there's none, as Singletons are not so popular these days (testability). We could easily have an annotation @Singleton that does the plumbing. If you feel that's useful please file a bugzilla.

Comment: @SvenEfftinge Thanks for this clear reply directly from the source! I'm aware that Singletons have lost their charm and I do know about the problems that can arise, nevertheless once in a while you'll need one and I find the Scala solution to this absolutely charming and actually better than the Singleton Pattern. I will ponder a request for an annotation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: @SvenEfftinge
No, there's none, as Singletons are not so popular these days (testability). We could easily have an annotation @Singleton that does the plumbing. If you feel that's useful please file a bugzilla.